# How do you use 'Plots of Land'?

Tags: bloons-td-5

How does one use the plots of land in bloons tower defense 5? The ones like "rifle range" where you have to purchase them with monkey money, and it will help you upgrade a specific type of tower. Do they act like banana farms in game, where they are one shot items that give a temporary boost, or are they permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specialty buildings are permanent.

Keep in mind they all have a disadvantage too, they improve something and give a negative bonus to something else, so buy only those who fit your strategy!

As an extra limit, you can only have one of them active at any time, so if you buy a rifle range and a super monkey lair you can only have one active, and not both. You can change wich one in the menu. Changing specialty building mid-game is not possible.

Comment: can you do some more research and then respond

Comment: can you confirm that this is the case

Comment: @Johann I updated the post with new information.